# How to write "dumb" quotes?

Tags: punctuation, babel

I need to cite a part of a string, which contains "dumb" quotes, and I want to keep them like this. When I write the quotes like they are, I face two problems:

1. The spacing behind a quote is missing
2. Quotes which are followed by a vocal are transformed to umlauts

For the example given below, my result document looks like:

> Example: ä quoted part"followed by text.

instead of

> Example: "quoted part" followed by text.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
Example: "a quoted part" followed by text.
\end{document}
```

How can I escape those quote to get the desired result? Obviously my problem is caused by the `babel` package, but I need this because I am writing a German document.

Comment: When you use `babel` with the `ngerman` option like you do (which is a good thing) `"a` is a shorthand `ä` (similar `"o` for `ö` and so on...)

Comment: Could you explain _why_ you want 'dumb' quotes? Normally this is only needed inside code blocks or other verbatim-like situations.

Comment: It's like a code block; I'm quoting a part from a text dataset and I want the text to be identical.

Comment: Then why don't you use `\verb+"a quoted part"+`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to obtain the `"` character is the one you've mentioned in your answer, but it doesn't work with every language (for example, it doesn't in Italian).

One more general way (avalaible in `T1` encoding but not in `OT1`) is to use the command `\textquotedbl`:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
Example: \textquotedbl a quoted part\textquotedbl\ followed by text.
\end{document}
```

produces the desired result in every language.

Answer (score 5):

If you needn't German shorthands (ie, `"a`, `"|`, `"-`, and the like), I think the easiest solution is:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\defineshorthand{"}{\textquotedbl}
\begin{document}
Example: "a quoted part" followed by text.
\end{document}
```

I think `\defineshorhand` can be used to set the value locally, inside a group, if necessary, but to be honest I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the ``` ``quote'' ``` construction (or `,,quote''`):

```
Example: ``a quoted part'' followed by text. % ,,a quoted part''
```

Or, which is must better, use the [`csquotes`](ftp://ftp.gust.org.pl/TeX/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf) package:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
Example: \enquote{a quoted part} followed by text.
\end{document}
```

What proses will be:

- `\enquote` will choose the appropriate quote marks based on language.
- No need of thinking what type of quote marks use for sub-quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe may question was a bit unclear; I know how to make typographically correct quotes and I'm using them throughout my document of course (actually, I'm entering them directly, and that works fine). But I want to quote a part from a text file, which uses the "dumb" (aka. straight) quote characters.

The suggested solutions here didn't work for me, but I just found my solution:

```
Example: "{}a quoted part"{} followed by text.
```